# How to fix wrong apple wallet notification icon

Tags: ios, notifications, wallet

I develop web server for distribute wallet passes. It’s working fine, I can download, update and void passes. Once day I add new passes template (Both have same passTypeIdentifier but different icon). I found something weird. I have 2 passes in my phone (Let say *p1* is pass from template *t1* with icon *i1*, *p2* is pass from template *t2* with icon *i2*)

I send notification to *p1*. Wallet app show icon *c1* (Correct)
https://ibb.co/nR2xHLz

I send notification to *p2*. Wallet app show icon *c1* (Incorrect)
https://ibb.co/2ncv1kr

Anybody found this issue, and how to solve it (With same passTypeIdentifier)?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you need to use a separate certificate or pass type. iOS caches quite aggressively and it assumes all combinations of passTypeIdentifier and pass type will share the same icon.